# Values from fields does not pass throug ajax to php

Tags: ajax, forms, phpmailer

I have a small contact form that almost works as i should. The file is uploaded and sent correctly, but all the other values from the input fields in the form does not pass throug the script. Does anyone see what I am missing?

Form:

```
<form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="path" id="path" value="projectpage">
<div><div class="textwidget custom-html-widget"><div class="moduletable pt-2 pb-2  mb-4">
<div class="custom  pl-2  pr-2 pt-4 pb-2  mb-4">
<div class="control-group form-group">
<div class="col"><label for="name">Navn:</label><input id="name" class="form-control" required="" type="text" data-validation-required-message="Skriv inn ditt navn.">
<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group form-group">
<div class="col"><label for="phone">Telefonnummer:</label><input id="phone" class="form-control" required="" type="tel" data-validation-required-message="Skriv inn et telefonnummer.">
<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group form-group">
<div class="col"><label for="email">E-post:</label><input id="email" class="form-control" required="" type="email" data-validation-required-message="Skriv inn en e-postadresse.">
<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group form-group">
<div class="col"><label for="message">Melding:</label><textarea id="message" class="form-control" style="resize: none;" cols="100" maxlength="999" required="" rows="10" data-validation-required-message="Skriv en melding"></textarea>
<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group form-group">
<div class="col"><label for="attachment">Vedlegg:</label> <input type="file" name="attachment[]" class="form-control border-0 w-auto" multiple="multiple">
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group form-group">
<div class="col"><label class="checkbox"> <input id="terms-and-conditions" name="terms-and-conditions" required="" type="checkbox" data-validation-required-message="Kryss av denne boksen hvis du vil fortsette"> Ved avkryssning samtykker du i vår <a href="/personvernerklaering" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl" rel="noopener noreferrer">personvernerklæring</a>. </label>
<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
</div>
<p class="help-block"></p>
<div id="success"></div>
<div class="col"><button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send oss melding</button></div></div>
</div></div></div></form>
```

JS: I think the problem is here, but I cant figure out what to change or add to make the data from the fields pass through along with the attachment.

```
$(function() {
    $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {},
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = new FormData(contactForm);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/wp-content/themes/bootstrap/mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
        method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
                success: function() {
                    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').append("<strong>Takk for din interesse. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry, it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });
    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

/* Exception class. */
require 'Exception.php';

/* The main PHPMailer class. */
require 'PHPMailer.php';



$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$from = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
$path = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['path']));



$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
$mail->AddReplyTo(($email_address), ($name));
$mail->setFrom('noreply@mydomain.no', 'Kontaktskjema på nettside');
$mail->addAddress('email@gmail.com', 'My NAME');
$mail->Subject  = 'Melding fra ' .$name. ' via kontaktskjema';
$mail->Body     = "Du har fått en melding via kontaktskjemaet på nettsiden.\n\n"."Her er detaljene:\n\nNavn: $name\n\nE-post: $email_address\n\nTelefon: $phone\n\nMelding:\n$message";

foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $k => $v) {
    $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$k], $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$k] );
}

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}     

return true;         
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of your `<input>` elements don't have `name` attributes.  So this won't include them:

```
new FormData(contactForm)
```

The file input works because it has a name:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" class="form-control border-0 w-auto" multiple="multiple">
                   ^----- here ------^
```

Add names to the rest of the inputs that you want included in the `FormData` object.

Comment: How on earth did I missed that. Thank you :-) This post can probably be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Like David said most of your `<input>` elements dont have name attributes and thats why the FormData method dont include them, you have two work arounds here:

1. Get all your data into an array using the id of each element and pass this array to your ajax e.g:

```js
let data = {

    name : $('#name').val(),

    email: $('#email').val(),

    .....

    };
```

2. add the name attribute to each input.

Hope it helps